# How can I filter a MultiPoint Z / xyz points against a 2d polygon

Tags: 3d, lidar, fiona

I would like to filter point data from LIDAR scans (3d) by parcel plot lines (2d).

I began with loading the lidar data into microsoft sql and performing a STIntersects between the MultiPoint and the Polygon. This provides a result, but loses it's 3rd dimension.

I then have tried loading the lidar .shp file into the [fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/index.html) python library, calling .filter() to narrow down the features, and traversing points checking .within() against the plot line polygon. This seems to work but is super slow.

Next I loaded the lidar .shp into the [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/index.html) python library. However there doesn't seem to be the best 3d support. The methods that were obvious to me were limited by the inability to get a .bound on the shape that included the 3rd dimension. So when I added the shape to the index is complained the bound was 2d and the shape 3d.

Finally I attempted to load each point manually into the rtree index so that I could correct the 3rd dimension manually on the insert.

I have not validated that rtree will even work once I have a complete index.

Has anyone figured out a non brute-force method?